# Add buttons Back, Forward, Play / Pause and a form for setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple slideshow with query but I need to add some buttons for back to previous slide, forward to next, play / pause the slideshow and an input form for change the interval.

Here's my code for slideshow:

```
var tempo = 3000;

var temporizzatore = function() {
  var elemento_visibile = $("ul#slider li").not(".hidden");

  elemento_visibile.addClass("hidden");

  if(elemento_visibile.is(':last-child')) {
    $("ul#slider li:first-child").removeClass("hidden");
  } else {
    elemento_visibile.next().removeClass("hidden");
  }
}

window.setInterval(temporizzatore, tempo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the way for the buttons...and change query code. But i don't be able to change the interval by the input form

Here my code...

```
        $('.ppt li:gt(0)').hide();

        $('.ppt li:last').addClass('last');

        $('.ppt li:first').addClass('first');

        $('#play').hide();

            var cur = $('.ppt li:first');

            var interval;

            var time= 3000;

            function start() {

                interval = setInterval( "forward()", time );
            }

            function stop() {

                clearInterval( interval );
            }

            function forward() {

                cur.fadeOut( 0 );

            if ( cur.attr('class') == 'last' )

                cur = $('.ppt li:first');
            else

                cur = cur.next();

                cur.fadeIn( 0 );
            }

            function goFwd() {

                stop();

                forward();

                start();
            }

            function back() {

                cur.fadeOut( 0 );

            if ( cur.attr('class') == 'first' )

                cur = $('.ppt li:last');
            else

                cur = cur.prev();

                cur.fadeIn( 0 );
            }
            function goBack() {

                stop();

                back();

                start();
            }

            function showPause() {

                $('#play').hide();

                $('#stop').show();

            }

            function showPlay() {

                $('#stop').hide();

                $('#play').show();

            }

            $('#fwd').click( function() {

                goFwd();

                showPause();

            } );

            $('#back').click( function() {

                goBack();   

                showPause();

            } );

            $('#stop').click( function() {

                stop();

                showPlay();

            } );

            $('#play').click( function() {

                start();

                showPause();

            } );

            $(function() {

                start();

            } );

    </script>
```